# How to re-arranging table by variable inside a function?

Tags: r

I'm writing a permutation function

```
  permutation<-function(seed,treatment,block_number,block_sizes,sample.size){
  b<-block_number
  s<-block_sizes  ## number of subjects per block
  set.seed(seed)
  m<-sample(s,size=b,replace = T) ## how the block is assigned
  treats<-vector("list",b)
  for (i in 1:b){
    treats[[i]]<-sample(rep(treatment,each=m[i]))## permutation within each block
  }
  assign<-unlist(treats)[1:sample.size]
  table<-data.frame(cbind(as.numeric(c(1:sample.size)),assign))
  return(table)
}

permutation(seed=1,treatment=c('a',"b"),block_number=4,block_sizes=c(2,3),sample.size = 15)
```

My output is a data frame like this:

```
   V1 assign
1   1      a
2   2      b
3   3      a
4   4      b
5   5      b
6   6      a
7   7      b
8   8      a
9   9      b
10 10      a
11 11      b
12 12      b
13 13      a
14 14      a
15 15      a
```

What I want is re-arranging the output table by treament, in a format like this (1,2,3 in the picture should be a,b in my case):

[image]

I tried taking out the table and can use subset() and cbind() to force combine the two columns, but I don't know how to write it inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a good practice to put vectors of different length in a table. Instead, you could use a list with one element per treatments.

However, you could modify you function to handle both case with a boolean argument. I used library `plyr` for `l*ply`-like functions because I found them very useful for handling input and output types. I used `plyr::` to explicitly call the functions. Of course, you could use `lapply` and convert to vector, list or table as you wish.

```r
permutation<-function(seed,treatment,block_number,block_sizes,sample.size, table = FALSE){
  b<-block_number
  s<-block_sizes  ## number of subjects per block
  set.seed(seed)
  m<-sample(s,size=b,replace = T) ## how the block is assigned
  treats<-vector("list",b)
  for (i in 1:b){
    treats[[i]]<-sample(rep(treatment,each=m[i]))## permutation within each block
  }
  assign<-unlist(treats)[1:sample.size]

  lres <- setNames(plyr::llply(treatment, function(treat) which(assign == treat)), treatment)

  if(table){
    nrow <- max(plyr::laply(lres, length))
    DF <- plyr::llply(lres, function(x) {
      vec <-vector("character", nrow)
      vec[1:length(x)] <- x
      vec
    })
    return(as.data.frame(DF))
  }
  lres
}
```

Then with the argument `table = TRUE` you would have the table you want with emply cells (`""`)

```
library(plyr)
permutation(seed=1, treatment=c('a',"b"), block_number=4, block_sizes=c(2,3), sample.size = 15, table = TRUE)
#>    a  b
#> 1  1  2
#> 2  3  4
#> 3  6  5
#> 4  8  7
#> 5 10  9
#> 6 13 11
#> 7 14 12
#> 8 15
```

However, it seems better to use list in case of different length element. (`table = FALSE`)

```
library(plyr)
permutation(seed=1, treatment=c('a',"b"), block_number=4, block_sizes=c(2,3), sample.size = 15, table = FALSE)
#> $a
#> [1]  1  3  6  8 10 13 14 15
#> 
#> $b
#> [1]  2  4  5  7  9 11 12
```